# XCode6 / Swift: PFQueryTableViewController "LoadingVIewEnabled" error

Tags: xcode, swift, pfquery

i hate xcode. anyway, im getting this "PFQueryTableViewController "loadingViewEnabled" error" ... im relatively ( very ) new to xcode, and am not sure how to fix this error. thanks in advance for the help

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hCuLdVo.png?1]